# How to model return type being of "either or" class in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, return

There is a method which currently returns an object that is of one of two classes.
I want to refactor it into something more intuitive that can easily be expanded if I ever add a third class etc.

What would be better way to implement this?

```
public Object getResult() {
  if (foo != null) {
    //foo is of class Foo
    return foo;
  } else {
    //bar is of class Bar
    return bar;
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this result used?  Is there some functionality that you depend on both having?  That would imply an interface of some sort, I think.

Comment: Have you seen `instanceof` operator?

Comment: As @Teepeemm said, Foo and Bar should share a common interface; otherwise you would break one of OOP principles by returning different objects (which then I suppose you would detect with an `instanceof` check)

Comment: I currently use "instanceof" on the other side of the application to distinguish between those classes. I just guess there must be a better implementation, thus the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to return a common interface or superclass of both objects.

If no such interface or class exists you could make one that defines the contract that both Foo and Bar will satisfy and the callers of getResult rely on.

If the two classes are completely disjoint I would recommend not using such a getResult since it isn't very meaningful in that case.